# Launch4j: Error when choosing version number

Tags: version, launch4j

I am using launch4j. 
I keep getting an error when tryping to convert my jar file to an exe. It definitely depends on the file version.

Inside the XML and the jar file I have the same Version number. I was creating exe with the version 2.0.20.0127 perfectly file, but then I came across the number 2.0.20.0128 where I got the error:

Compiling resources
C:*filepath\launch4j8902622138564912245rc:3: digit exceeds base
Line 3 has errors...
FILEVERSION 2, 0, 20, 0128
net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed: C:*filepath\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:*filepath\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j8902622138564912245rc C:*filepath\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j5028065172838345433o

I tried even higher numbers eg 2.0.20.0777 which works perfectly fine, but as soon as I enter an 8 or an 9 I get that error.

Any ideas what might be the reason?
Thank you already in advance.

Best regards,
Dani

Answer (score 2):

The FILEVERSION consists of four numbers, each of them is interpreted separately. Numbers with a leading zero are recognized as octal numbers, hence only digits 0...7 are valid. In your case '0128' is the problem, because it contains the digit '8'.